# Axis breaks at noon each day of ggplot2 chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add day axis labels at noon for each day of my chart. Currently, it adds the labels at midnight, but I'd prefer it if those labels were spaced midway between each day, while retaining grid lines denoting midnight. I tried using `hjust` but the results didn't look very good. Is there a way to do this?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

dat <- data.frame(time_value=seq(as.POSIXct("2011-07-01"), length.out=24*30, by = "hours"),
                  usage_value=sample(1:10, 24*30, replace=TRUE),
                  group=1)
dat$week <- format(dat$time_value, '%W')
dat <- subset(dat, week == 27)

ggplot(dat, aes(x=time_value, y=usage_value, group=1)) + 
  scale_x_datetime(breaks='day', labels=date_format('%A')) +
  geom_line()
```

Comment: not sure, but maybe look at using date_breaks in ``breaks = date_breaks(...)``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way.

First, create the noontime data. This is quite easy using `seq.Date`:

Then add a `geom_vline` to your plot:

```
noon <- data.frame(
  x=with(dat, seq(from=min(time_value), to=max(time_value), by="1 day"))+12*60*60
)

ggplot(dat, aes(x=time_value, y=usage_value, group=1)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(data=noon, aes(xintercept=x), col="blue")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, though I'm looking for a way to shift the axis labels to where those noon lines are.

Comment: @ErikShilts Just pass the date sequence Andrie constructed to the breaks argument: `scale_x_datetime(breaks = noon$x,...)`.

Comment: passing a dates sequence works if you are hardcoding it but my suggestion is to just subtract 12 hours from the data and let ggplot2 handle the labels